# How do I set jquery pagination show page 1 on load

Tags: jquery, pagination

I'd like to set page 1 to show first when I load my page using the pagination from this link

[jquery pagination](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination)

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation: https://github.com/gbirke/jquery_pagination#readme

It seems that the plugin has an option named :

current_page :- The page that is selected when the pagination is initialized. Default: 0

So I think you could do something like:

```
$("#News-Pagination").pagination(122, {
        items_per_page:20,
        callback:handlePaginationClick,
        current_page : 1
});
```

HTH :)